# Database 1NF violation

Tags: database

i have 2 tables

Musicians which they can play many instruments

and

Instruments which can be played by 1 musician at a time

so the relation between the two table is :

Musicians can play 1 to many instrument

instruments can be played by 0..1 musician at a time
how can I not violate the 1NF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `instruments` table would have a nullable foreign key `musician`.  `musician` would have no column for instrument.

Comment: if i do that then i would have 2 musicians who can play the piano for example.

Comment: what i am trying to say is : if i have a piano in instruments and john and walt in musicians they both can play the piano but only one of them can play it at a time

Comment: So you would have three tables.  `Musician`, `PlayableInstrument`, and `Instrument`. PlayableInstrument would have FKs into Musician and Instrument. `Instrument` would have a FK into `Musician`, along the lines of `Currently Being Played By`

Comment: wouldn't that change the relation between the tables ?

Comment: No, it would add a *new* relation.  You've got two relationships here. "Can play" and "Is playing".  They are different.